# TECoreException: The server's error could not be parsed as XML. No SOAP fault found

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am getting below error while trying to fetch versionControlClient object using TFS java SDK. Any leads what could cause this ?

we are using TFS-2010

```
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: The server's error could not be parsed as XML.  No SOAP fault found.
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:105)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.LocationExceptionMapper.map(LocationExceptionMapper.java:32)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.internal.LocationWebServiceProxy.connect(LocationWebServiceProxy.java:76)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.connect(LocationService.java:756)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.checkForServerUpdates(LocationService.java:841)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.findServiceDefinition(LocationService.java:174)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.locationForCurrentConnection(LocationService.java:532)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.webservice.DefaultWebServiceFactory.getServerDataProviderEndpointPath(DefaultWebServiceFactory.java:523)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.webservice.DefaultWebServiceFactory.newWebService(DefaultWebServiceFactory.java:252)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.getWebService(TFSConnection.java:891)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.client.DefaultClientFactory$7.newClient(DefaultClientFactory.java:231)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.client.DefaultClientFactory.newClient(DefaultClientFactory.java:91)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.getClient(TFSConnection.java:1495)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSTeamProjectCollection.getVersionControlClient(TFSTeamProjectCollection.java:377)
at com.blueoptima.connectors.scr.vcs.tfs.TFSExtractor.authenticate(TFSExtractor.java:389)
at com.blueoptima.connectors.scr.SCR.extract(SCR.java:360)
at com.blueoptima.connectors.BOpInfraExtractor.run(BOpInfraExtractor.java:201)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.InvalidServerResponseException: The server's error could not be parsed as XML.  No SOAP fault found.
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.examineBodyForFault(SOAPService.java:1094)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:732)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:475)
at ms.ws._LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.connect(_LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.java:384)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.internal.LocationWebServiceProxy.connect(LocationWebServiceProxy.java:70)
... 19 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.util.xml.XMLException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.microsoft.tfs.util.xml.DOMCreateUtils.parse(DOMCreateUtils.java:648)
at com.microsoft.tfs.util.xml.DOMCreateUtils.parseStream(DOMCreateUtils.java:451)
at com.microsoft.tfs.util.xml.DOMCreateUtils.parseStream(DOMCreateUtils.java:353)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.examineBodyForFault(SOAPService.java:1082)
... 23 more
```

Comment: How did you fetch *versionControlClient* object using TFS java SDK? Could you add some related code?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT

 `TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(URI.create(url), credentials);

vcc = tpc.getVersionControlClient();`

Comment: @ChunkyyGary According to the error info, this issue may related to you are using the wrong url.  The Server URL must contain the TFS projetc colletion, such as `http://myserver:8080/tfs/your collection name` Please double check this. For more details, take a look at similar error info in this issue [SOAP exception whilte trying to connect to TFS](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31233)